# Many folders with numbers in C: drive root directory in backup

Tags: windows-10

This is with Windows Backup (Windows 7) in Control Panel.

There are folders called "Backup files [number]" which is normal.

[image: Normal numbered folders]

However, in those folders, namely **52** and **53**, there are folders numbered 1 - 295

[image: Not very normal numbered folders 1]

[image: Not very normal numbered folders 2]

Those folders contain Gradle files.

[image: File in a folder]

[image: File in another numbered folder]

These files do not exist on the drive by typing `C:\<number>`, and are not even marked **system / hidden** files. I'm not sure if this is from something I installed, malware, or just some known bug with Windows Backup [windows 7]

Can someone tell me what is causing this?
I do not compile using Gradle, only Maven. However, I do have Gradle installed. Maybe it's Gradle acting up?

[image: My C folder with hidden items shown]